# Extract and organise values from a structure

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following structure as an output of computation:

```
structure(c(2L,1L,1L,2L), .Label=c("high","low"), 
    class="factor", prob=c(1,0.667,0.8,0.333))
```

What is the best way to extract information from this structure and represent in a data frame?

For instance:

```
Val  Label   Prob
  2   low       1
  1  high   0.667
  1  high     0.8
  2   low   0.333
```

I have tried `as.numeric()`, `unname()` but neither worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can assign the parts we'd like. And as in most problems there are a few ways to get the attribute:

```
data.frame(Val=as.integer(x), Label=x, Prob=attr(x,"prob"))
  Val Label  Prob
1   2   low 1.000
2   1  high 0.667
3   1  high 0.800
4   2   low 0.333
```

Comment: If you're code golfing `as.integer(x)` could be `c(x)`

Comment: Yes we were talking about it in chat. going for readability here.

Comment: Hahaha No idea what's gettin into me.